# Как сгруппировать по двум полям?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM  `Messages` WHERE  `FromUser` =1 OR  `ToUser` =1 GROUP BY  `ToUser` , `User_ID` ORDER BY  `Created` DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Пишу сообщения пользователей, нужно сгруппировать отправителя и получателя в одну группу. Типа как вконтакте. Помогите плиз.

Ответ:

```
SELECT *, FromUser+ToUser AS GroupingUser 
FROM `Messages` 
WHERE  
`FromUser` =1 OR  
`ToUser` =1 
GROUP BY  `GroupingUser` 
ORDER BY  Created` DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Если есть еще идеи пишите

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,concat(ToUser,fromUser) as k FROM `messages` WHERE ToUser=1
UNION
SELECT *,concat(fromUser,ToUser) as k FROM  `messages` WHERE fromUser=1
ORDER BY k, id
```

Comment: верно. только лучше `union all`.

Answer (score 0):

эммм...а вот так разве не подойдет?

```
SELECT fromUser, ToUser, Count(*)
FROM Messages
WHERE 
    <что-то там> = <другое что-то там>
GROUP BY fromUser, ToUser 
ORDER BY  Created DESC
```

Comment: не пойдет в данном случае если
fromUser=1 а ToUser =2
и
fromUser=2 а ToUser =1
Сгруппируются в разные строки